# How to add new functionality into ejabberd server

Tags: ejabberd

I have created a `.erl` file named "confirmDelivery.erl" and compile it successfully, A `beam` file named "confirmDelivery.beam" has been created.

All these files are in `/etc/ejabberd/`. Now I wanna add the functionality of this file into `ejabberd`, But I don't know how to link my file with ejabberd server.

Please help me, I will be really really thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your beam files in the path of the Erlang VM to be able to use them. You should have a look at where are other ejabberd module for example and place it in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks to you, i have added module successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your beam file in etc/ejjaberd/ebin folder and call it from ejabberd debug mode.
use command:
ejabberdctl debug